# Can't access public var in PHP

Tags: php

I'm having trouble accessing a variable from a method declared public in the same class in PHP7, so far I have the following:

```
    class H  {

        public $Q=array();

        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();          
            $Q[]="SELECT";
        }
        private function sas(){
            if(isset($_REQUEST['n']) && $_REQUEST['n']!=""){
                $q=$this->query($_REQUEST['n']);
            }
        }
        private function query($n){
            if($n==="a")
                return $Q[0];
        }
     }
```

After calling `sas()` I get the following error message `<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: Q in <b>C:\xampp\apache\apps\a.php</b> on line <b>66</b><br />`. Please help!!

Comment: @Rizier123 right, but now I get an array to string conversion error, how do I access the first element in Q?

Comment: As you already did with `[0]`

Comment: `return $this->Q[0]` ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per @Rizier123 's comment `$Q` needs to be `$this->Q`. To access the first element of the array, use `$this->Q[0]`. Every time you're accessing the public variable (or any other instance variable) within the class you'll need to specify `$this` in order to reference the current object.

Comment: That's it, I was missing how to access public vars

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of issues with your code. I change your code and made the following test `class` which works:

```
class H  {
    public $Q=array();

    public function __construct(){
        //parent::__construct();          
        $this->Q[]="SELECT";
    }
    // changed from 'private' to 'public'. 
    // Also passing in $n (for example code only).
    public function sas($n){
        if(isset($n) && $n!=""){
            $this->query($n);
        }
    }
    // Not sure what you are trying to do, so changed code to make
    // things clear when stuff changed.
    private function query($n){
        if ($n==="a")
            $this->Q[0] = "changed";
    }
 }

$h = new H();
$h->sas("a");
$x = new H();
$x->sas("x");
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($h->Q);
var_dump($x->Q);
echo '</pre>';
```

The result is:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "changed"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "SELECT"
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is basic rule:

```
$this->classMembers
```

In your case is:

```
$this->Q
$this->Q[0]
```